# Can Blend 4 work with Visual Studio 2010 C# Express?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, blend

Can someone let me know? 
Thanks

Comment: Why wouldn't it? Perhaps you can ask about a specific feature and we can see.

Comment: I guess he means read and write same project files, i.e. are VS2010 C# express and VS2010 full project files and solutions completely compatible.

Comment: There's nothing special about Visual Studio Express editions; they just have less included features.

Comment: They also do not support add-ins and the reason they are seperate versions is because each version in say the professional edition are actually plugins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blend 4 and Visual Studio 2010 use the same project file format and are fully compatible.